# How to break the make of a new line?

Tags: line-breaking

I'm trying to break the make of a new line by `\begin{itemize}` for a more appropriate view of `longtable`. I can't find how to achieve this.
Any help, please ?

```
\begingroup
\setlength{\LTleft}{-20cm plus -1fill}
\setlength{\LTright}{\LTleft}
\begin{longtable}{|p{3cm}|p{4cm}|p{7cm}|}
\hline
1 & 2 & 3 \tabularnewline
\hline
\begin{itemize} \item[-] ABC.\item[-] DEF \end{itemize} & AAA & BBB. \tabularnewline
\hline
\multicolumn{3}{l}{} \\[-7pt]  
\caption[]{Description.}
\end{longtable}
\endgroup
\vspace{0.5cm}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{ltablex}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}

\begingroup
\begin{longtable}{|p{3cm}|p{4cm}|p{7cm}|}\hline
1 & 2 & 3 \tabularnewline\hline
\vspace{-\baselineskip}
\begin{itemize}[topsep=0pt] \item[-] ABC.\item[-] DEF \end{itemize} & AAA & BBB. \tabularnewline
\hline
\end{longtable}
\captionof{table}{Description.}
\endgroup

\begingroup\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|p{3cm}|p{4cm}|X|}\hline
1 & 2 & 3 \tabularnewline\hline
\vspace{-\baselineskip}
\begin{itemize}[topsep=0pt] \item[-] ABC.\item[-] DEF \end{itemize} & AAA & BBB. \tabularnewline
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\captionof{table}{Description.}
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

By the way: In your case it makes more sense to use package `ltablex` which is a combination of `tabularx` and `longtable`

Comment: Thank for your quick response, can you please show me how to use these, please ? **Note : ** I'm making a report, the `[topsep=0pt]` haven't work in.

Comment: see my edited answer. Use my example first and then adopt it to your source.

Comment: only the `\vspace{-\baselineskip}` has fixed the issue.

Comment: sure! `tabularx` was a hint for a better tabular type setting!

Comment: Broken links in PSTricks site: http://i.stack.imgur.com/5hjmT.png